# What is a one-line solution to get everything except the last item in a slice without using the last item's index?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

In Python, I can do:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = a[:-1] #1,2
```

Rust has syntax to get a slice of a array [range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) where you provide the last index, non-inclusive:

```rust
let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
let b = &a[0..2]; // [1, 2]
```

If I use `-1`, it causes a compiler error:

```rust
let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
let b = &a[0..-1];
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `usize: std::ops::Neg` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:3:19
  |
3 |     let b = &a[0..-1];
  |                   ^^ the trait `std::ops::Neg` is not implemented for `usize`
```

How can I do this?

example :

i want to transform "x1::x2::x3::...::xn" to "x1::x2::x3::...xn-1"
in python the one line solustion shoud be

```py
case_1 = "a::b::c";
ret = case1.split("::")[:-1]
```

but what it the one line soluction for rust

```rust
let case_1 =  "a::b::c";
let ret = case_1.split("::").collect::<Vec<_>>() //what could i do next?
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think [`split_last`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_last) is what you are looking for: it returns an optional 2-tuple containing a reference to the last element and a slice up to (but excluding) the last element.

I.e. `a.split_last().unwrap().1` gets what you request (`unwrap` assumes that `a` is non-empty).

If you want to modify the values, there's also its cousin [`split_last_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_last_mut).

Answer (score 10):

You can use `-1` as long as you add `vec.len()` in advance:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", &a[0..a.len() - 1]);
}
```

Because OP asked for a one-liner, you can remove the newline and use non-idiomatic Rust formatting:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3]; println!("{:?}", &a[0..a.len() - 1]);
}
```

Comment: @CongWu I don't understand, how is `&a[0..a.len() - 1]` **not** a one-line solution?

Comment: OP asked for a solution without using the position of the last item directly; ie, avoiding `a.len()`.

Comment: sorry for my express not clearly, i thought this answer is not one-line solution cause you must declare an array in other "line". i have given a example in the updated question.

Comment: Note that this oneliner does not work if array reference needs to be mutable.
`my_func(&mut a[..a.len() - 1])`

Answer (score -3):

Probably not what you want, since you seem to be after a less verbose solution, but you could use `pop`; with vectors, it mutates the original vector.

```rust
let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut init = a.clone();
&init.pop();
assert_eq!(init, &[1, 2]);
```